# Pass parameter to request

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to verify the unicity in the db of one of a form's value. Idea is to return a message to the user when he hits the Submit button.

Where is the best place to do that ? I tried creating a middleware that redirect to the same form if the value is not unique, but i lost the old values as the middleware is processed before the request.

I also tried to add the checking function in the Request itself but I can't find documentation on how to modify it

So  my request will look like

```
    /**
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'item' =>'required',
        'item.code' => 'required|unique:owned_by',
        'item.owned_by' => 'present',
    ];
}
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function attributes()
{
    return [
        'item.code' => trans('items.fields.code'),
        'item.owned_by' => trans('items.fields.owned_by'),
    ];
}
```

How to I get a difference between :
the item.code is not definer and the item code is not unique for this user ?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use the built in Validation to handle this for you? http://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation

Comment: Please clarify your question with more details, what have you tried so far in code, are you submitting form using ajax ? and do you mean old values of form input ?

Comment: You can try putting the form data in session. And in your view, change the code. If there is session data the form will be of the old value. Otherwise blank.

Comment: I can't use validation as I need to check in the db if the form value is unique for a particular. Is there a way to process some code in the validation ?

Comment: `unique` rules checks in db for duplicate entry. share your form and tried code we will try to help you.

Comment: I read about that with the link sent by FatBoy, but is there a way to say : this code needs to be unique for this customer. My table is code,..,..,..,customer_id

Comment: so will `code` be always unique separately or unique with `owned_by` +`code` ?

Comment: Code will be unique for this owned_by but Code is not set as unique in the table